# Performing a Binary Search

Tags: algorithm, search

I am performing a binary search , let say i have to find the minimum value of `x` such that `black_box(x)` gives me `true` result.

Property of `black_box(x)`

- If `black_box(x)` gives me true then `x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4....upto infinty` all gives me `true`

For **Integer Value**  this is simple binary search

```
 start=0;
 end = Max;
 ans=-1;
 while(start<=end){

    mid =(start+end)/2;
   if(black_box(mid)):
       end =mid-1
       ans=mid;
   else: start=mid+1;
}
```

What if i want a `floating point` integer upto 2 decimal , how should i do binary search ?

Comment: If `end = Inf`, how can you determine the middle of it? Even for `int`s that's not the case.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's smiple expression , Inf will the maximum value , just a representation , hope you get this

Comment: yeah but there are ways to represent integers with no maximum value (or at least not until you run out of memory, like `BigInteger` in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You simply iterate until `start` and `end` differ no more than `0.01`. So the stop condition is now:

```
while(end-start > 0.01){
```

Furthermore as you specified in the comment yourself, you cannot increment/decrement `start` and `end` in your algorithm, since the indices are not discrete. The full algorithm now is:

```
 start=0;
 end = Max;
 ans=-1;
 while(end-start > 0.01){

    mid =(start+end)/2.0;
   if(black_box(mid)):
       end =mid
       ans=mid;
   else: start=mid;
}
```

This works because at each iteration `start` is a *lower bound* on the exact value and `end` is an *upper bound* on the exact value. If both no differ more than `0.01`, we know it is in the range between `start` and `end` and since the difference is less than 0.01, it is exact by two decimals.

Nevertheless, your algorithm is wrong in the sense that by setting `end = Inf`, you cannot work with this. You can perhaps use the maximum representable value, or use exponential increment search first as a preprocessing step.

Comment: What about the increment i am increment with +1

Comment: @NarendraModi: simply set `end = mid` and `start = mid`, so without increments/decrements.